# Displaying image path in PHP from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I would like to display multiple images on my index page. Doesn’t matter if they are displayed in any order.

Each of the images have their image path and their unique ID. I have the following code but it is not displaying anything:

```
  <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_image", $connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $ID = $row['name'];
        $file =  $row['file_path'] ;
        echo '<img style="margin: -32.5px 0 0 0;" alt="" src="'.$file.'">' ;
    }       
    ?>
```

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message or anything? What happens if you output the result of `$row`, i.e. with `print_f()` or `var_dump()`?

Comment: no error. It is displaying nothing.

Comment: Then output the result of the `$row` variable to see what’s coming back from your query. Also, don’t use the `mysql_query()` and related functions; they’re deprecated: http://uk3.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: did you check the generated HTML code? How does it look?

Comment: C:/wamp/www/HTML/ae948b6e79aca1d46c5c27711a245e35.jpgC:/wamp/www/HTML/uploadedimages/59a42c4b9d8fbb7a4311dafb0cedeefb.jpgC:/wamp/www/HTML/uploadedimages/dcd2f489b510a82f2a3e7cb83b0698cb.jpg

this 3 locations are printed at one go.. However what I wanted was to display it one at  a time..

Comment: Those are local file paths, not URLs. You need to translate them into web accessible URLs by removing 'C:/wamp/www/HTML' from the beginning.

Comment: do you have reading permissions to the folder where the images are ?

Comment: yeah it has all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you should start to debug your code, as example :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $file =  $row['file_path'] ;
   echo $file; continue;
   //...
}
```

and see if you get expected result.

EDIT:

what about var_dump($result) ?

Comment: I’d print the entire `$row` array, just to check there actually *is* a key called `file_path`, let alone what its value is.

Comment: C:/wamp/www/HTML/ae948b6e79aca1d46c5c27711a245e35.jpgC:/wamp/www/HTML/uploadedimages/59a42c4b9d8fbb7a4311dafb0cedeefb.jpgC:/wamp/www/HTML/uploadedimages/dcd2f489b510a82f2a3e7cb83b0698cb.jpg

this 3 locations are printed at one go.. However what I wanted was to display it one at  a time..

Comment: your site is online, or localhost?